# Stein & Shakarchi, Complex Analysis, Ch.2 Ex.7

Tags: integration, general-topology, complex-analysis

Suppose $f : \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic, and $d = \sup_{z,w \in \mathbb{D}} |f(z) - f(w)|$. Show that
$$ 2 |f'(0)| \leq d$$
This entire exercise is a complete mystery to me and I am mostly just doing computations out of shear desperation, but I have no true idea what I am doing. The hint states that
$$ 2 f'(0) = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{|z|=r} \frac{f(z) - f(-z)}{z^2} \ dz, \ 0 < r < 1$$
I have no idea where they managed to derive this formula from but moving on we find that with the parametrization $z(t) = r e^{2 \pi i \theta}$
$$ \int_{|z|=r} \frac{f(z) - f(-z)}{z^2} \ dz = \int_0^1 \frac{f(re^{2 \pi i \theta}) - f(-rr^{2 \pi i \theta})}{re^{2 \pi i \theta}} \ d \theta$$
Taking absolute values
$$ 2| f'(0)| = \int_0^1 \frac{\left|f(re^{2 \pi i \theta}) - f(-re^{2 \pi i \theta})\right|}{r} \ d \theta$$
Now I get stuck. Cearly we have $re^{2 \pi i \theta} \in \mathbb{D}$. The next step I am not sure about but is the following a valid step
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\left|f(re^{2 \pi i \theta}) - f(-re^{2 \pi i \theta})\right|}{r} \ d \theta \leq \int_0^1 \frac{\sup_{u \in \mathbb{D}}\left|f(u) - f(-re^{2 \pi i \theta})\right|}{r} \ d \theta$$
Then similarily because $-re^{2 \pi i} \in \mathbb{D}$ we have
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\sup_{u \in \mathbb{D}}\left|f(u) - f(-re^{2 \pi i \theta})\right|}{r} \ d \theta \leq \int_0^1 \frac{\sup_{u,w \in \mathbb{D}}\left|f(u) - f(w)\right|}{r} \ d \theta$$
This however does not give me the desired result as now I would have
$$ 2|f'(0)| \leq \frac{d}{r}$$
Any suggestions? I am out of my comfort zone as I don't really feel I have the tools to "check" the validity of all the steps I have used.

Comment: Now let $r \to 1$. The formula is Cauchy's integral formula for the derivative parametrised in two different ways, and added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have no idea where they managed to derive this formula from

The Cauchy integral formula (for derivatives). Recall that

$$f'(\zeta) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z\rvert = r} \frac{f(z)}{(z-\zeta)^2}\,dz$$

for $\lvert\zeta\rvert < r$. Thus, setting $\zeta = 0$ we obtain the first summand,

$$f'(0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z\rvert = r} \frac{f(z)}{z^2}\,dz.$$

It remains to see that the second part

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\lvert z\rvert = r} \frac{-f(-z)}{z^2}\,dz$$

also evaluates to $f'(0)$. There are many ways to see that, we can use the parametrisation $t \mapsto - re^{2\pi i t}$ for the circle, we can look at the function $g(z) = -f(-z)$ and note $g'(0) = f'(0)$, ...

Having that out of the way, your following steps are fine and you correctly derive

$$2\lvert f'(0)\rvert \leqslant \frac{d}{r}.\tag{$\ast$}$$

Now all that's left to do is to note that $(\ast)$ holds for *all* radii $0 < r < 1$, so

$$2\lvert f'(0)\rvert \leqslant \inf_{0 < r < 1} \frac{d}{r} = d.$$

Comment: Brilliant, now I see it. We find a lower bound for $d / r$ and then of course the infimum of the possible values of $r$ must be larger than this lower bound! Fantastic!